# CImg and Jpg format fix?

Tags: c++, image, jpeg, cimg

Well my issue is basically that I am trying to use Cimg and load an image. It works for .ppm and .bmp files, but when I try and load a .jpg image it doesn't work. I read up somewhere I must have the right image magick installed, etc. I installed the most recent version but no luck. Also I tried to look for `convert.exe`, and I cannot find it in the image magick folders. Only a header file called convert, and I tried to add it as well to the project but it won't help.

Please someone help me. I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out alone.

Im using codeblocks on windows 10.

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate of the previous question - it is almost certainly caused by the names of the ImageMagick binaries changing at v7+ of ImageMagick.

Comment: You need to uninstall and then re-install **ImageMagick** and when you re-install, you must tick/check the box marked *"Install LEGACY names"* which means it will create the binary called `CONVERT.EXE` that **CImg** is looking for. You can also call `CImg::imagemagick_path()` to set the path of where `CONVERT.EXE` is installed to help things along. The reason for this is that at v7, `CONVERT.EXE` was renamed to `MAGICK.EXE` to avoid confusion with Windows's own `CONVERT.EXE` which converts filesystems from FAT32 to NTFS.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Please consider re-opening.

Comment: @sascha Please consider re-opening.